# Sample size calculation for crossover design using dependent t-test - role of $\rho$?

Tags: sample-size, random-effects-model, sample, crossover-study

I am trying to do a sample size calculation for a 2x2 crossover study. I have access to previous studies whereby I can get covariate adjusted estimates of the variability of the responses (from a random effects model). In order to avoid simulating the full random effects model, I am convinced I can use sample size calculations for a t-test for two dependent samples, since in a crossover design each subject gives two responses, each one under a different treatment, and these will surely be correlated. However in a dependent t-test the within-subject correlation appears to matter, whilst in a random effects model it does not. I am confused and would like to reconcile the two approaches, since apart from the inclusion covariates, the correlation should matter for the modelling approach too?

**T-test:**
Let $Y_{jk}\sim N(\mu_{j},\sigma^{2})$ be the response of the $k^{th}$ subject, $k=1,..N,$ for treatment group $j=1,2$, and $Cov[Y_{k1},Y_{k2}]=\rho\sigma^{2}$. Then we estimate $\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}$ with $\bar{d}=(1/N)\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^{N}d_{k}$, where $d_{k}=Y_{k1}-Y_{k2}$. Given that $Var[\bar{d}]=2\sigma^{2}(1-\rho)/N$, we see for fixed $\sigma^{2}$ that our estimator precision increases as $\rho$ increases.

**Random effects model**: Assume no covariate effects (such as period effects), two randomisation sequences giving a treatment order of $T_{1}/T_{2}$ for sequence $i=1$ and $T_{2}/T_{1}$ for sequence $i=2$, and $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ subjects in each sequence, where $N=n_{1}+n_{2}$.

A standard model appears to be $Y_{ijk}=\mu_{[ij]}+S_{ik}+e_{ijk}$, where $j=1,2$ indexes periods, and $k=1,...,n_{i}$. Here $\mu_{[ij]}$ is the treatment applied in sequence $i$ in period $j$, $S_{ik}\sim N(0,\sigma^2_{s})$ and $e_{ijk}\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$.

Using this model, within a sequence the within-subject covariance $Cov[Y_{k1},Y_{k2}]=\sigma^{2}_{s}=\rho(\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}_{s})$ is the covariance between two responses in the different treatment groups - just as we assume it is for the t-test.

However given that $d_{1k}=Y_{11k}-Y_{12k}=\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}+e_{11k}-e_{12k}$ and $d_{2k}=Y_{21k}-Y_{22k}=\mu_{2}-\mu_{1}+e_{21k}-e_{22k}$ then $\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}$ is estimated with $(1/2)(\bar{d_{1\cdot}}-\bar{d_{2\cdot}})$. But here $Var[(1/2)(\bar{d_{1\cdot}}-\bar{d_{2\cdot}})]=(2\sigma^{2}/4)(n_{1}^{-1}+n_{2}^{-1})$ - no $\rho$ involved!

So the random effects model implies the within-subject correlation does not affect estimator precision at all - why the difference?